# ¿Cómo hago que se active al hacer click en un <li> y desactivar los demás?

Tags: php, html, css

**Este es mi ejemplo pero no desaparece los demas li cuando se activa otro**

- Lo que hace mi código como pueden ver en el ejemplo hace su submenú desplegable y oculta entre otras cosas pero  estaba viendo como activar  los `<li>` si pudo pero después tuve un error que cuando se activa el otro ya no se desactiva cómo puedo lograr solucionar todo esto.
- hace submenú ocultando  alguna que sepa de código  active con bootstrap
- Pero al hacer click se activa
- Pero al hacer click en otro `<li>` el anterior no se desactiva

> Alguna Sugerencia

```css
.icon-left{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.icon-right{
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Members Area</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/stylesIndex.css" >
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<div class="col-sm-3 nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

    
        <!-- Personas -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li id="li" class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true" id="persona">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">
                        <i class="fa fa-users icon-left"></i>Personas<span
                            class="ti-arrow-down glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down icon-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div style="height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false" id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-list submenu">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Empleados</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Guardia</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Visitantes</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Vehiculos-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="nav-link" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">
                        <i class="fa fa-car icon-left"></i>Vehiculos<span
                            class="ti-arrow-down glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down icon-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div style="height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false" id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-list">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Vehiculos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Escaleras</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Ingresos y salidas-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="nav-link" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">
                        <i class="ti-user glyphicon glyphicon-sort icon-left"></i>Ingresos y Salidas<span
                            class="ti-arrow-down glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down icon-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div style="height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false" id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-list">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Vehiculos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Visitantes</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Sucursales-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="nav-link" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">
                        <i class="ti-user glyphicon glyphicon-equalizer icon-left"></i>Sucursales<span
                            class="ti-arrow-down glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down icon-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div style="height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false" id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-list">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Sucursal</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Cooperativa</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Municipio</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Cuentas-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="nav-link" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="false">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2"><i
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-user icon-left"></i>Cuentas
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div style="height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false" id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Reportes-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="nav-link" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="false">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse6"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2"><i class="fa fa-book icon-left"></i>Reportes
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div style="height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false" id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Generardor Qr-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">

            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="nav-link" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="false">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse7"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2"> <i class="fa fa-qrcode icon-left"> </i>Reportes
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div style="height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false" id="collapse7" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas usar javascript o jQuery.  Algo asi:

```js
$(".nav li").click(function() {
    $(".nav li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');    
});
```

```css
.icon-left{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.icon-right{
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Members Area</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/stylesIndex.css" >
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<div class="col-sm-3 nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

    
        <!-- Personas -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li id="li" class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true" id="persona">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">
                        <i class="fa fa-users icon-left"></i>Personas<span
                            class="ti-arrow-down glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down icon-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div style="height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false" id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-list submenu">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Empleados</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Guardia</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Visitantes</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Vehiculos-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="nav-link" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">
                        <i class="fa fa-car icon-left"></i>Vehiculos<span
                            class="ti-arrow-down glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down icon-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div style="height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false" id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-list">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Vehiculos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Escaleras</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Ingresos y salidas-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="nav-link" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">
                        <i class="ti-user glyphicon glyphicon-sort icon-left"></i>Ingresos y Salidas<span
                            class="ti-arrow-down glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down icon-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div style="height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false" id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-list">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Vehiculos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Visitantes</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Sucursales-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="nav-link" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">
                        <i class="ti-user glyphicon glyphicon-equalizer icon-left"></i>Sucursales<span
                            class="ti-arrow-down glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down icon-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div style="height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false" id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-list">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Sucursal</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Cooperativa</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i>Municipio</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Cuentas-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="nav-link" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="false">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2"><i
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-user icon-left"></i>Cuentas
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div style="height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false" id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Reportes-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="nav-link" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="false">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse6"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2"><i class="fa fa-book icon-left"></i>Reportes
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div style="height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false" id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Generardor Qr-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">

            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="nav-link" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="false">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse7"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2"> <i class="fa fa-qrcode icon-left"> </i>Reportes
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div style="height: 0px;" aria-expanded="false" id="collapse7" class="panel-collapse collapse"
                role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: alanfcm gracias amigo eso si me sirvio